# How does icecast/shoutcast sync audio for multiple connections?

Tags: http-live-streaming, shoutcast, icecast

I've learned by attempting to make this that network really affects live streams. For example, if your streaming an MP3 at 4096 bytes until 0. The slow connection will buffer and skip where as the fast connection will buffer to fast and greatly lose sync. How does shoutcast/icescast account for this?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: **they don't**.

Stream playback will commonly drift apart by 5-60 seconds. This is inherent to this type of streaming and not a bug/problem.

Traditional broadcast radio also experiences similar effects. There may be a difference in delay between different transmitters (frequencies) and if simulcast over satellite or DAB/digital terrestrial broadcast there will be a significant delay when comparing that to e.g. 'analog FM'. Of course all receivers using the same method/frequency will be roughly in sync.

The technical reason in case of HTTP streaming is, as you noticed, in the buffers. The largest impact is due to the client side buffer size. Player software will commonly increase the buffer size significantly if it gets a buffer under run (e.g. due to a bad/congested connection).

That said there is of course the very basic "sync", that two clients connecting at the exact same time will be sent bitstream from the same point in time, while a client connecting later will be sent bitstream matching what the other two clients are receiving *at that point in time*. This means that looking at it on a larger scale, the clients are all at roughly the same point and receiving identical data at almost the same time - that's because it's a *"live stream"*, if it were a static file, every client would start from the very beginning and there would be no relation at all.

PS: If you are looking for a solution that has a hard reference sync to wall clock, then VoIP related technologies are the way to go. For local networks there are various protocols that can synchronize receivers down to signal phase.

Comment: I know that complete sync isn't possible due to multiple factors. But, shoutcast/icecast seem to be off by seconds where as im off by minutes at times. I've tried creating a FPS system but I still cant seem to get the same results as the others. I can't really understand the language icecast is coded in so looking at its source just gets me lost. The only languages I know are python/js/Lua but nothing seems to be made with them that I could reference.

Comment: The very basic underlying concept is a *circular buffer*. It gets filled from the source client at a (simplified) constant rate. When a client connects it gets hooked up near/at the position of the end pointer and starts receiving data at the same time as it comes in. If for some reason the client can't keep up with receiving data, then it can fall behind inside this buffer and then possibly catch up again. If at any time it reaches the start pointer of the buffer('empty' from its perspective), it gets dropped as the server can't ensure continuity of the data.